# Why data duplicate when using concurrent threads

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
import requests
from gevent.threadpool import ThreadPoolExecutor

def postRequest():
    postapi = requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL, json=groups, headers=headers)


pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)

with open("car.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r]
    groups = {}

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r[ 'bmw' ])):
        items = [ ]
        for i in g:
           #data process

        pool.submit(postRequest)

pool.shutdown(wait=True)
```

My code is working well as expected but the problem is some data will be duplicated. I think it happens the threads duplicate which posts the same request at the same time because it is a concurrent method. May I know how to avoid this happen?

Updated

```
def postRequest(message):
    postapi = requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL, json=groups, headers=headers)
    return message


pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)

with open("car.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r]
    groups = {}

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r[ 'bmw' ])):
        items = [ ]
        for i in g:
           #data process

        future = pool.submit(postRequest,("hello"))
        print(future.done())
        sleep(2)
        print(future.result())

pool.shutdown(wait=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`submit`](http://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.threadpool.html#gevent.threadpool.ThreadPoolExecutor.submit) function takes the arguments that should be passed to the function. Perhaps try passing them in?

```
    pool.submit(postRequest, x, y, z)
```

Comment: I updated the code, the `future.done and result` both return false.